# Excel - Macro - how to define an event handling method for all sheets in workbook

Tags: excel, vba, event-handling

I am trying to call a macro whenever a cell got clicked. This applies to all the sheets in my workbook. But from the search I found that mostly it is defined for a specific worksheet. I want to make it for all sheets. Even in future if a new sheet got created, it should have the same functionality like other sheets. Can anybody say how to achieve this?

Note: I am using excel 2010. Answers related to other versions also OK for me.

Comment: Chip Pearson passed away a few years ago but for most of us Excel "experts" he was the go-to address when we learned our trade. Read how he answered your question. http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/AppEvent.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should customise the `SheetSelectionChange` event, making sure you confirm that you are triggered from a worksheet object

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

  If TypeName(Sh) = "Worksheet" Then
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sh
    
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ws.Range(Target.Address)
    
  
    With r.Interior
        .Color = 65535
    End With
  
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI this goes in the `ThisWorkbook` code module

Comment: @johnnieL How to add this code in excel. I added one MsgBox to know ehether the code is reaching that point, then pasted it in the vb code tool,saved. But when I click the cell it is not showing up.

Comment: From the answer of "JohnnieL" and the comment of "Tim Williams" I got the answer. Thank you.